# I want to get notify in active browser tab once upload process is complete in another tab using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Using Jquery/Javascript how to pop message in active browser tab when a process is complete in another browser tab(Ex: file uploading in one browser tab). It is MVC application. Please suggest approach, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think possible you can try this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236828/javascript-communication-between-tabs-windows-with-same-origin/12514384#12514384) link or possible look at using signalR to implement your solution, personaly I have never used signalR but believe it should point you to the right solution. The idea would be to send messages to the server that check for any tabs opened by the the user and act according to that. There is also a gihub project called [IWC-SignalR](https://github.com/slimjack/IWC-SignalR) that aims to remove the limit of concurrent connection from the same browser using signalR.